# select2 laravel selected data not working

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

iam trying to fetch the data in select but it is not showing anything??

```
//Controller query
$productColor = Product::where("id","=",$id)->select('product_color')->pluck('product_color')->toArray();




<select class="form-control color" style="width: 315px; height: 39px !important; background-color: #1a2035 !important;" value="{{ $data->product_color }}" name="product_color[]" placeholder="Enter Colors" multiple="multiple">
                                      @foreach($colors as $color)
                                        <option value="{{ $color->color_hexcode }}"
                                            {{ in_array($color->color_hexcode,$productColor) ? 'selected' : '' }}
                                        >
                                            {{ $color->color_name }}
                                        </option>
                                      @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: So is the $data variable not working? Can you clarify what is showing, and what parts are working/not working?

Comment: No data variable is working I think in_array is creating problem is there any way to retrieve selected on the selet2

Comment: So is this line `{{ in_array($color->color_hexcode,$productColor) ? 'selected' : '' }}` not working? As in if you look at the rendered html it doesn't have `'selected'` on the row you would expect? Maybe instead of `'selected'` try `selected="selected"`

Comment: no sir it is not working but I tried    {{ in_array('["'.$color->color_hexcode.'"]', $productColor) ? 'selected' : '' }}   and selected just one color it is showing but when I selected multiple color it is not working problem with $color->color_hexcode should be in array

Comment: It’s hard to debug without knowing what’s in the variables, can you Log `$productColor` and `$colors` and show the result of those Logs? It would also be helpful if you added the rendered HTML of the <select> (like copy and paste the select from inspect element). That way we can see what part is going wrong

Comment: now comment is not allowing to post... what to do??

Comment: I tried this code.  @if($data->contains('product_color', $colorHex)) selected="selected" @endif    but it is giving error. Call to undefined method App\Product::contains()

Comment: Can you Log the variables you are using and add them to the your question, like `Log::info($data)` and do the same with `$colors` and `$productColor`. Then go to your laravel.log file and add the results. Also it would be helpful to add the rest of your controller function and the rendered HTML.